# slash in token can not be used in url of angular 4

Tags: angular, routes

in angular 4 for confirming email I use token in url that maybe has slash/, and if it has slash it redirects to home page. what is the solution of this problem?

this is my routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: 'confirm-email/:userIdCode', component: 
ConfirmEmailComponent}]
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and this is my email confirm component:

```
export class ConfirmEmailComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private signupService: 
SignUpService) {}

 private url: string;
 private userId: any;
 private code: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.url = params['userIdCode'];
  const splitted = this.url.split('|');
  this.userId = splitted[0];
  this.code = splitted[1];
  this.signupService.sendConfirmEmailData(this.userId).subscribe( result => 
  console.log(result));
 });
 }
 }
```

thank you.

Comment: remove the slash from the token

Comment: you mean in server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the slash when passing it to the url. For example say your token is `12/34`. This should be encoded to `12%2F34`. So ultimately your url is `/confirm-email/12%2F34`. Now when angular pulls in the parameter (for example with this.activatedRoute.paramMap), it will automatically decode it and give you the parameter `12/34`

Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/llai-forward-slash-encoding?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) demoing this.

Comment: thank you for your demo, but a problem I didn't understand how can I encode the token that I don't know what it is. In your demo you assign token 12/34 but when I don't know what it is how can I write the app module 'rediredTo:'?

Comment: @AmirGh in a real world app, you wouldn't have the wildcard route (`**`) point to the confirm-email route. It would instead point to a 404 page of some sort.